# PHP SAML Authentication WSSE JAX-WS

Tags: php

I knew it's very hard to present it with simple words. but it really confused me a lot.
I'm going to code for an Authentification class in PHP.

Here's the technical points:
 1. saml2p:AuthnRequest XML(in php, we have to transform them into object,but how?)
 2. simplexml array to object and object to array.
 3. WSSE Header in JAX-WS
 4. AuthnRequestType

And my codes and questions:
this should be the authnrequest XML but I dont know how to put it into the method as a parameter in SoapClient.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://http://localhost/SAML/objectoarray.php"
    ID="551e5cd8-7f50-4dcd-bc85-eb625bb12da7" IssueInstant="2013-01-14T06:17:05.138Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <saml2:Issuer>applpf.pioneer.jp</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#551e5cd8-7f50-4dcd-bc85-eb625bb12da7">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>4RzD9oGu0D+pWD1ZZfrb83WsWL8=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>dxZE/60oe3+rlIbVUcCa1isgfOGM0pi5XRaKPsvFtyJ3RAw9AoLzN0nYngTD9Dj/TbWdu1wCW+gekrBUtbhKkBU7xBuBWtQvLxHCB7mHxiOZZqMSYR4kjzzmHEWqSbsG3oYoWhDBXyfHWnlztk8onI9sysiBMboJe7yybmne0PilZkLmkpZcTUefUKyrCQF1l49BIF5J5R+QC7Uh6dHCNXx1zFesVKBqmaWumlKCXssycEUFfNqoTD9rtlMnQ5U6aQEEfYpRClMS8SYdsY+K9daM0lEEncjfZrpUaZR5jQJo+M1CHSmfrv7qU36Hqi+vNWBK8YIH1raMkg17ZMYBhA==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

I just save them as a pure xml and converted them into an array.

Like :

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://applpf.pioneer.co.jp/" ID="0011e577-5e4a-46b5-9703-888294c0bd66" IssueInstant="2013-01-14T06:19:51.626Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Version="2.0" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><saml2:Issuer>applpf.pioneer.jp</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#0011e577-5e4a-46b5-9703-888294c0bd66"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>PWG+OxqzVzA0piHjtvsjh/MlChA=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>gcoF7BZAJ0W85PK9tbSvJT0aTATQTysFmi+FxyLfZvhA7nHtmYqqXfy9r2r73Jai1qCruPUGmOx3IpjP9wjBPnCCCx/gHW8UjPdAJlLhNBK17svKEmx4uMranN5M/MLrFnqkQduuzmMXl/xio3+iJs4Tldo/5wL4L99Go58l+BMGurEdgmh744E7v+yvniS1thPjc2E07Dlb0o5rdlqkEYYPL2CR0r8er3IXdT2+939iaoD8h+B3v9zu6M6qNcOTfVz9HmV54/sIB15u9cl7efDIsHj4/uAlnqZTg66EgrD44Cj0J2b7z8mo1Qdd+8b59vRA6DtRXw3DnIE3hKeMRw==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></saml2p:AuthnRequest>');
$xml_object = simplexml_load_string($xml->asXML());
```

finally I put this into methods as parameters

```
$authnSample->loginByCustomer($xml_object,"\$00astest","password");
```

in CustomerLoginService class
we do

```
class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader {

private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/asis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';


    function __construct($user, $pass, $ns = null) {
        if ($ns) {
            $this->wss_ns = $ns;
        }

        $auth = new stdClass();
        $auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns); 
        $auth->Password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);

        $username_token = new stdClass();
        $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns); 

        $security_sv = new SoapVar(
            new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns),
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);
        parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
    }
}
```

and then

```
$wsse_header = new WsseAuthHeader($this->userid, $this->password);
$this->soapClient = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
$this->soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($wsse_header));
```

but eventually I still got the error like this:

> Exception:SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error in
>   C:\php5\www\PINE_FW_AS_PHPProject\com\pioneer\pine\fw\as\object\CustomerLoginService.php:137 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   SoapClient->_*doRequest('*_call('login', Array) #2
>   C:\php5\www\PINE_FW_AS_PHPProject\com\pioneer\pine\fw\as\object\CustomerLoginService.php(137):
>   SoapClient->login(Array) #3
>   C:\php5\www\PINE_FW_AS_PHPProject\com\pioneer\pine\fw\as\Authentication.php(76):
>   CustomerLoginService->login(Array) #4
>   C:\php5\www\SAML\test_authreq01.php(48):
>   Authentication->loginByCustomer(Array, '$00astest', 'password') #5
>   {main}

can anyone told me , how can I make right access to the Auth Server in a proper way or much simple way.

Comment: Let me have a little bit comment on my questions:
the first problem which I met was how to convert the xml with namingspaces into an object and then an object convert to xml with namingspace.
the second problem was how to create these two points for AuthnRequest XML by PHP
$signature->KeyInfo
$X509Data->X509Certificate
the third problem was how to transmit the parameters userid and password to WSSE header by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Im doing a very similar authentication for some web service. Here is the way i do this. One function to convert an array to SoapVar Object.

```
function arrayToSoapVarObject($array=array(),$nameSpace=NULL,$nodeName=NULL){
    $object=array();
    foreach ($array as $key=>$val){

        if (is_array($val))
            $object[$key]= new SoapVar(arrayToSoapVarObject($val,$nameSpace), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $nameSpace, $key, $nameSpace);
        elseif (is_string($val))
            $object[$key]=new SoapVar($val, XSD_STRING, NULL, $nameSpace, NULL, $nameSpace);
        elseif (is_object($val))
            $object[$key]=new SoapVar($val, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $nameSpace, NULL, $nameSpace);
    }

    return $nodeName!=''?new SoapVar((object)$object, NULL, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $nodeName, $nameSpace):(object)$object;
}
```

Now, simply declare an array in the way it requires the WSSE

```
$strWSSENS = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext";

$token=array(

        'UsernameToken'=>array(
                'Username' => 'XXX',
                'Password' => 'YYY',
                'Organization' => 'ZZZ',
                'domain' => 'DEFAULT',
        ),
);

$objToken=arrayToSoapVarObject($token,$strWSSENS,'UsernameToken');
```

This objToken is a perfectly well formed SoapVar Object...So we use to make the WSSE Header Security

```
$objSoapVarWSSEHeader = new SoapHeader($strWSSENS, 'Security', $objToken,true, 'https://actor.com');


try {

 $client= new SoapClient($wsdl);
 $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($objSoapVarWSSEHeader));
 $response=$client->__soapCall('Action',array($arguments),null,null,$output_headers);
}catch (SoapFault $fault){

    echo $fault->getMessage();
}
```

I guess this approach is a bit simple.